# Compare fields in 2 files and write only missing or different fields

Tags: awk

I have 2 LDIF output prepared to one line each object separated by "|" and all attribut fields are sorted.
I want to write first field contain dn: when a field is missing or has a different value in second file. If it's missing i need a marker add and a marker replace if it's different. If all fields are identical, nothing should be written.
My script with 2 loops works, but is to slow for millions of rows. I'm trying this now with awk, but I don't know how to compare 2 files with it.

**File 1**

```
dn:abc|attribut a: 10|attribut b: 11|attribut c: 12
dn:xyz|attribut a: 10|attribut b: 11|attribut c: 12
```

**File 2**

```
dn:abc|attribut a: 10|attribut b: 11|attribut c: 12
dn:xyz|attribut a: 10|attribut c: 11
```

**Needed Output**

```
dn:xyz|add attribute b: 11|replace attribute c: 12
```

Line with dn:abc is identical in both file, so it's not written in output file. 
Line dn:xyz has difference, so I need this first field contain "dn:xyz". Next field attribut a: 10 is identical so nothing do. Next field is missing in file 2, I need "add attribut b: 11". Last field attribut c: is in both files but the value differs in file 2, I need "replace attribut c: 12" the value from file 1.

Comment: Sorry i didn't now that, I have now accepted on the other question a solution

Comment: and please include your script in the question, so maybe we can find why it is so slow and tell you how to improve it

Comment: you can use several tool like grep and awk depending the final purpose. I think  a awk have more flexibility on info to provide. a simple `grep -v -F -f File.2 File.1` is normaly enough

Comment: Quite unclear and the sample does not reflect all the requirements clearly. Please, consider more thorough example and post some work done.

Comment: are dn:abc, dn:xyz, etc sorted in same line ordering in both files? if dn:abc exists in file 1 does it exist in file 2? can file 2 contain dn:pqr that does not exist in file 1?

Comment: can you get the LDIF file in standard format?

Comment: To question can a dn exist in only one file; normaly not if this happend I've got a bigger issue. To other question, yes original output is a normal LDIF. I think it's easier to get it wortk in one line, but if you now a way from a normal LDIF output I will be better.

Comment: there are tools specifically to create change files from LDIF ifi it is in standard form

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to the question, however, from the comments it seems that the files to be compared are being created from standard LDIF formatted files.

There already exist tools to take two LDIF files and output the changes needed to reconcile them. For example:

- [OpenDJ](https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenDJ/) provides `ldifdiff` in its `opendj-ldap-toolkit` package
- [ldifdiff](https://github.com/nxadm/ldifdiff) is a Go tool
- [ldiff](https://fruit.je/ldiff) is an unmaintained Perl script to "generate differences between two LDIF files"
- [ldap-diff](http://nicku.org/software/) - another Perl script

One of these tools is likely to be much more reliable than something new from scratch.

Some background reading on LDIF, including change records:

- [rfc2849](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2849)
- [notes from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10773_01/doc/oim.1014/e10531/ldif_appendix.htm)